# Eq instance has some strange comparisons

Tags: haskell, comparison, ghc, typeclass, deriving

I have made an image processing module that defines a `Pixel` type as a `Color` and `Location`. `Pixel`, `Color`, and `Location` derive `Eq`, as I may want to compare pixels between multiple images.

`Eq` suits my needs for comparing pixels to see if they're exactly alike, which is what I wanted. A strange side effect of instancing `Eq` is that comparing 2 unlike pixels with the same `Location` with either `<=` or `>=` results in `True`, but `False` for `==`, `<`, and `>`.

```
data Color = Color { red   :: Int
                   , green :: Int
                   , blue  :: Int
                   , alpha :: Int
                   } deriving ( Show, Eq )

data Location = Location { x :: Int
                         , y :: Int
                         } deriving ( Show, Eq, Ord )

data Pixel = Pixel { color    :: Color
                   , location :: Location
                   } deriving ( Show, Eq )

instance Ord Pixel where
         compare (Pixel _ a) (Pixel _ b) = compare a b
```

Then in *ghci* some tests.

```
>let a = Pixel (Color 0 0 0 255) (Location 0 0)
>let b = Pixel (Color 0 0 1 255) (Location 0 0)
>let c = Pixel (Color 0 0 0 255) (Location 0 0)
>let d = Pixel (Color 0 0 0 255) (Location 0 1)
>a == b
False
>a /= b
True
>a < b
False
>a > b
False
>a <= b
True
>a >= b
True
>a == c
True
>a /= c
False
>a > c
False
>a < c
False
>a >= c
True
>a <= c
True
>a == d
False
>a /= d
True
>a > d
False
>a < d
True
a >= d
False
a <= d
True
```

It seems that my defining `Ord` for a `Pixel` has affected these comparisons, which is understandable. *d* shows that `Location` affects comparison. The part I'm confused about is how *a* is both `>=` and `<=` *b* without being `==`, `<`, or `>`.

EDIT: In case anyone wants to use any of this code, I'll include this snippet that fixes the problem. Be sure to remove `Eq` from the `Pixel` definition.

```
instance Eq Pixel where
            (Pixel _ a) == (Pixel _ b) = a == b
            (Pixel _ a) /= (Pixel _ b) = a /= b
```

This allows for comparison for `Location` only. Enjoy! :)

Comment: It's worth noting that an Ord instance for Location arguably doesn't have a sensible geometric interpretation in 2D (the default lexicographic ordering biases the horizontal component). That said, an Ord instance is necessary if you want to index a Data.Map by Location. Similarly colour arguably only has a sensible ordering for certain colour models - e.g. you could order HSV colours on their darkness/lightness.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The part I'm confused about is how `a` is both greater than or equal to and less than or equal to `b` without being equal, less than, or greater.

By introducing your custom `Ord` instance for `Pixel`, while still deriving 
`Eq`, you have an interesting consequence:

- pixels will have full structural equality, based on both their color and location
- however, to give them an ordering, you ask to ignore the color.

This is going to make things behave strangely, as some things will compare as
`EQ` (based on having the same location only), while at the same time, if you 
test for equality with `(==)`, the values will be inequal, since the color is
also included.

*Essentially you've made the `Eq` and `Ord` instances unsound.*

Either derive both `Eq` and `Ord`, getting full structural equality and 
ordering, or manually write an `Eq` instance that discards color information,
as your existing `Ord` instance does.

Comment: I'd like to accept both your answers, but since this one has information on how to fix it, I will accept this one.

Answer (score 3):

Because your Ord instance ignores color but your derived Eq instance will not.   `a == b`  is false because  `==`  is a method of the Eq typeclass and the derived method will account for color.
 `a <= b`  is true because  `<=`  is part of the Ord typeclass and your implementation of compare ignores color which means  `compare a b == EQ`  if a and b have the same Location, regardless of their Color.